# C# Linq to XML - Parse Nested Object List

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, nested-lists

I currently have a XML file format that goes something like this (whitespace and ellipses added for readability):

```
<root>
    <Module>          //Start with list of Modules
        <ModuleParams>
        </ModuleParams>
    </Module>
    ...

    <DetectLine>      //Now a list of DetectLines
        <DetectLineParams>
        </DetectLineParams>

        <Channels>    //List of Channels embedded in each DetectLine
            <Channel>
                <ChannelParams>
                </ChannelParams>
            </Channel>
            ...

        </Channels>
    </DetectLine>
    ...

</root>
```

Classes structured as follows:

```
public class Module
{
    public ModuleParams { get; set; }
}

public class DetectLine
{
    public DetectLineParams { get; set; }
    public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    public ChannelParams { get; set; }
}
```

The list of Modules and DetectLines are easy to parse with Linq to XML.  However, parsing the Channel list for each DetectLine is not as apparent to me.  Can this even be done with Linq to XML?  I would prefer not having to restructure things to work with a XMLSerializer.

Initial Code (openXML is a OpenFileDialog.  Already checked for good filename):

```
List<Module> myModules;
List<DetectLine> myDetectLines;
XDocument config = XDocument.Load(openXML.FileName);

myModules =
         (from myElements in config.Descendants("Module")
          select new Module()
          {
              ModuleParam1 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam1"),
              ModuleParam2 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam2"),
              ...
          }).ToList<Module>();

myDetectLines =
          (from myElements in config.Descendants("DetectLine")
           select new DetectLine()
           {
              DetectLineParam1 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam1"),
              DetectLineParam2 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam2"),
              ...

              // ?? Add Channels list here somehow...
           }).ToList<DetectLine>();
```

Comment: Give use you code for Modules and DetectLines

Comment: My reasoning for keeping the classes so general is because the actual parameters are up to me (this is a config file for my program that I define and save.  The format just makes it easy to read/debug/write manually).  I've added my current parsing methodology to show what I'm looking for.  I don't need someone to solve the XML or classes themselves, just advice on parsing with the Linq query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
XElement detectLine = XElement.Parse(@"<DetectLine>      
        <DetectLineParams>
        </DetectLineParams>

        <Channels>    
            <Channel>
                <ChannelParams>
                </ChannelParams>
            </Channel>
            ...

        </Channels>
    </DetectLine>
");
```

you can do e.g.

```
DetectLine dl1 = new DetectLine() {
  DetectLineParams = ...,
  Channels = (from channel in detectLine.Element("Channels").Element("Channel")
             select new Channel() {
                 ChannelParams = new ChannelParams() { ... = channel.Element("ChannelParams").Value }
             }).ToList();
```

We really need to see more of the concrete C# class code to spell out how to set up the complete query.

[edit]
To fit in with the code you have now posted:

```
myDetectLines =
          (from myElements in config.Descendants("DetectLine")
           select new DetectLine()
           {
              DetectLineParam1 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam1"),
              DetectLineParam2 = (string)myElements.Element("ModuleParam2"),
              ...

              Channels = (from channel in myElements.Element("Channels").Element("Channel")
                 select new Channel() {
                     ChannelParams = new ChannelParams() { ... = channel.Element("ChannelParams").Value }
                 }).ToList();
           }).ToList<DetectLine>();
```

Comment: Thing is there are multiple DetectLines defined in the XML file.  This requires me to create a list of DetectLines where each individual DetectLine has a list of Channels (just added my initial parsing method to explain what I mean).

Comment: How did I miss that?  Lesson learned: Never code on an empty stomach.  Thanks very much sir!